# Captured output from cmd is empty in Windows PowerShell ISE but has value when run in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
$filepath = "rabbitmq-plugins.bat";
$argument1 = 'enable';
$argument2 = 'rabbitmq_management';
$cmd = "&'$filepath' $argument1 $argument2";

$errormessage = $executioncontext.invokecommand.invokescript($cmd) | out-string;
write-host  $errormessage;
```

This code produces an error message. When I run the script in Windows PowerShell ISE the $errormessage variable is always empty. When I run the script in PowerShell, the variable gets populated and I can see the error text.

Why is the $errormessage variable empty if I run the script in Windows PowerShell ISE?

Comment: Does `InvokeScript()` throw an error/exception? If it throws = no output = nothing to assign to `$errormessage`.

Comment: In a try-catch, nothing is caught. An error message is assigned when the script is run in PowerShell.

Comment: Does it output the expected message if you remove everything else (eg. just run `$executioncontext.invokecommand.invokescript($cmd)` without piping to `Out-String` or assigning it to a variable)?

Comment: If I just run this: $executioncontext.invokecommand.invokescript($cmd); In PowerShell I can see the error message I'm expecting i.e. the output of the .bat file. When I run it in Windows PowerShell ISE then I get nothing.

Comment: Specify  a _fully qualified path_ to the `rabbitmq-plugins.bat` file  in `$filepath`. Maybe different _current directory_ `$PWD.Path` in ISE vs Posh?

Comment: I specified the full path $filepath = "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.9\sbin\rabbitmq-plugins.bat" but I still get nothing in the $errormessage variable

Comment: I also tried this: $executioncontext.InvokeCommand.invokescript($cmd) *>&1; in Windows PowerShell ISE but it does not show me anything coming from the invokescript command

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround:
After this is called

```
$executioncontext.invokecommand.invokescript($cmd);
```

you can use the $Error object

```
Write-Error $Error
```